# valores repetidos en javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy utilizando un plugin llamado datatables.js, que te permite crear tablas con muchas funciones integradas. En fin, para que funcione, hay una sección donde te pide un apartado llamado columnas. estoy intentando hacer columnas dinámicas, hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
var columnasTabla = [
        { data: "C_prove" },
        { data: "Descripcion" },
        { data: "Rfc_proveedor" },
        { data: "Nombre_comprador" },

    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < sucursales.length; i++) {
        var intento = i;
        columnasTabla.push({
            render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return "<label><input type='checkbox' class='sucursalCheckbox' name='sucursalCheckbox' sucursalID='" + sucursales[intento] + "' checked /><span></span></label>"
            }
        });
    }
```

datatables js no permite directamente poner como columna un checkbox, pero permite utilizar una función para imprimirlo. la variable `sucursales` es un array que contiene 2 strings, "001" y "003". La idea sería que, al momento de acomodar las columnas con datatables.js, el sucursalID debería ser 001 en la primera columna, y 003 en la segunda. por alguna razón, cuando corro el código, siempre se queda con el último indice del array, es decir, todos salen con "003" en el campo sucursalID. ¿porqué sucede esto? no importa cuantos elementos tenga el array, siempre se queda con el último.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está relacionado con el concepto de *closure*. Ya que los elementos del array son funciones, y desde su cuerpo hacen referencia a la variable `intento`, la definición de esas funciones contiene una referencia a la variable externa `intento`, para así poder "cerrar" su definición.

El problema es que todas las funciones se refieren a la misma variable `intento`, la cual vale "003" al final del bucle. Por tanto cuando, una vez terminado el bucle, intentes ejecutar cualquiera de esas funciones mediante algo como `columnasTabla[0].render()`, por ejemplo, la referencia interna que esa función tiene a `intento` se resuelve con el valor 3, que es el valor que en ese momento tiene dicha variable.

Dicho de otro modo, la variable `intento` no se evalúa en cada iteración del bucle, sino que queda simplemente "referenciada" desde la función, y eso es lo que constituye la *closure*. Para cuando la función asociada a `render` se ejecute, la variable `intento` ya habrá cambiado de valor y tendrá el que le corresponda a la última iteración del bucle.

Para resolver el problema, tienes que forzar a que la variable intento se evalúe en cada iteración del bucle, en vez de una vez terminado el bucle, como parte de la definición de la función.

Una forma de lograrlo es hacer una función anónima que reciba como parámetro el `intento` y devuelva como resultado la función que quieres asociar al `render`, que tenga ya ese intento particular, e invocar a dicha función anónima en cada iteración del bucle. Es decir:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sucursales.length; i++) {
    var intento = i;
    columnasTabla.push({
        render: function(intento){  
                  return function (data, type, full, meta) {
                           return "<label><input type='checkbox' class='sucursalCheckbox' name='sucursalCheckbox' sucursalID='" 
                                  + sucursales[intento] 
                                  + "' checked /><span></span></label>"
                         };
                }(intento);  // <-- Invocamos inmediatamente la función anónima para cada intento
    });
}
```

Con este truco, la referencia a `intento` que hay en la función interna, se refiere al parámetro de la función anónima externa, y ese parámetro toma un valor diferente en cada iteración del bucle (lo mismo le podíamos haber pasado `i` como parámetro y así ahorrarnos el `var intento=i;`)